# Cartesian equation of a surface

Tags: surfaces

Given the following surface
$$\sigma(u,v)=(\cos u,2\sin u,v)$$
I gotta find a cartesian equation of it. What I could conclude was
$$4x^2+y^2=4$$
Is there a way to associate $x$ and $y$ with $z$?

Comment: What you have is correct. $z$ is independent. That's what cylinders do!

Answer (score 1):

Because $z=v$ is independent of the other coordinates, your surface is the cylinder, aligned with the $z$-axis, with $4x^{2}+y^{2}=4$ as its cross section. (So in this case, it is an elliptical cylinder.)